# CoffeScript Easy & Simple CountUp and CountDown

Tags: count, coffeescript, counter, delay, countdown

i have a really simple CountUp from 0 to 10 Code-Line here, but I want it to CountDown 3 Seconds after it has reached 10 back to 0 again. And this in an interval. Somebody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

```
      Utils.interval 3, ->
         zahlValue = 0

           Utils.interval 0.05, ->
              if zahlValue < 10
                 zahlValue++
                zahl.html = zahlValue   


           Utils.delay 3, ->
             Utils.interval 0.05, ->
             if zahlValue = 10
                 zahlValue = 0
                zahl.html = "0"
```

Comment: (1) What is `Utils`? (2) Your CoffeeScript indentation is not consistent nor does it (probably) reflect the structure of your code.